# Machine Learning reward artificially capping

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-gym

So when I run this, it works perfectly, however, for some reason the reward caps at 200. I'm not sure what could be causing this. I'm new to machine learning and this is my first project, so sorry if I am missing something stupid.I hypothesize that `done` is triggering before I want it too, but playing with that hasn't led to anything. Thanks so much.

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
discount_rate=.95

# TODO Build the policy gradient neural network
class Agent:
     def __init__(self, num_actions, state_size):

        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, state_size])

        # Neural net starts here

        hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.input_layer, 8, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)
        hidden_layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden_layer, 8, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

        # Output of neural net
        out = tf.layers.dense(hidden_layer_2, num_actions, activation=None)

        self.outputs = tf.nn.softmax(out)
        self.choice = tf.argmax(self.outputs, axis=1)

        # Training Procedure
        self.rewards = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ], dtype=tf.float32)
        self.actions = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ], dtype=tf.int32)

        one_hot_actions = tf.one_hot(self.actions, num_actions)

        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out, labels=one_hot_actions)

        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy * self.rewards)

        self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, tf.trainable_variables())

        # Create a placeholder list for gradients
        self.gradients_to_apply = []
        for index, variable in enumerate(tf.trainable_variables()):
            gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            self.gradients_to_apply.append(gradient_placeholder)

        # Create the operation to update gradients with the gradients placeholder.
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2)
        self.update_gradients = 
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients_to_apply, tf.trainable_variables()))



def discount_normalize_rewards(rewards):
    discounted_rewards = np.zeros_like(rewards)
    total_rewards = 0

    for i in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
        total_rewards = total_rewards * discount_rate + rewards[i]
        discounted_rewards[i] = total_rewards

    discounted_rewards -= np.mean(discounted_rewards)
    discounted_rewards /= np.std(discounted_rewards)

    return discounted_rewards


#initialize the training loop
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Modify these to match shape of actions and states in your environment
num_actions = 2
state_size = 4

path = "./cartpole-pg/"

training_episodes = 1000
max_steps_per_episode = 20000
episode_batch_size = 5

agent = Agent(num_actions, state_size)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)

if not os.path.exists(path):
   os.makedirs(path)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

total_episode_rewards = []

# Create a buffer of 0'd gradients
gradient_buffer = sess.run(tf.trainable_variables())
for index, gradient in enumerate(gradient_buffer):
    gradient_buffer[index] = gradient * 0

for episode in range(training_episodes):

    state = env.reset()

    episode_history = []
    episode_rewards = 0

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):

        if episode % 100 == 0:
            env.render()

        # Get weights for each action
        action_probabilities = sess.run(agent.outputs, feed_dict={agent.input_layer: [state]})
        action_choice = np.random.choice(range(num_actions), p=action_probabilities[0])

        state_next, reward, done, _ = env.step(action_choice)
        episode_history.append([state, action_choice, reward, state_next])
        state = state_next

        episode_rewards += reward

        if done:
            total_episode_rewards.append(episode_rewards)
            episode_history = np.array(episode_history)
            episode_history[:,2] = discount_normalize_rewards(episode_history[:,2])

            ep_gradients = sess.run(agent.gradients, feed_dict={agent.input_layer: np.vstack(episode_history[:, 0]),
                                                                agent.actions: episode_history[:, 1],
                                                                agent.rewards: episode_history[:, 2]})
            # add the gradients to the grad buffer:
            for index, gradient in enumerate(ep_gradients):
                gradient_buffer[index] += gradient

            break

    if episode % episode_batch_size == 0:

        feed_dict_gradients = dict(zip(agent.gradients_to_apply, gradient_buffer))

        sess.run(agent.update_gradients, feed_dict=feed_dict_gradients)

        for index, gradient in enumerate(gradient_buffer):
            gradient_buffer[index] = gradient * 0

    if episode % 1 == 0:
        saver.save(sess, path + "pg-checkpoint", episode)
        print("Reward: " + str(total_episode_rewards[-1:]))


env.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Episodes for Cartpole terminate when the pole falls and at [200 successful steps](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/c8f81495441864e380967d8735e7ca6d09c52f7b/gym/envs/__init__.py). See the max_episode_steps in the linked file if you want to change this. The reason there is a 200 step max is to make evaluating trials easier (ie you always get episode ends so you can evaluate episode stats) and so that the environment doesn't get stuck in a never ending trial.

```
register(
id='CartPole-v0',
entry_point='gym.envs.classic_control:CartPoleEnv',
max_episode_steps=200,
reward_threshold=195.0,)
```